# Shouldn't there be a preposition 'like' in "She looked every bit a princess."?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

> She looked every bit a princess.

Doesn't this sentence need the preposition *like*, as in "She looked every bit like a princess."?

Comment: In a word, no. Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9917. If you ignore all the hullabaloo about which article should be used (Rule #1: _Never overthink an article_; Rule #2: _Never overthink the article_), you'll find your structure here mirrors some of the examples there. The phrase _something of a_ (or _every bit a_) can be used to mean _much like a_. So, "She looked every bit a princess" is essentially the same as, "She looked like a princess in every way."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are using *look* as *appear*, the comparative preposition *like* may or may not be used. The following sentence is from Oxford dictionary.

[You made me look a complete fool!](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/look)